# Visual Studio Code Remote Explorer: Modifying Default Mamba Environment Activation

Tags: linux, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, mamba

I am using Visual Studio Code's Remote Explorer to access my CentOS server, and I am using Mamba to manage my environments.
I want to change the default environment that Mamba opens to from "base" to a self-created environment named "bioinfo."

I've looked at other people's questions and modified my `~/.bashrc` 
file by adding `conda activate bioinfo` to the end of it. I also ran `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`, but this only partially solved my issue. It activates the "bioinfo" environment only when I first connect to bash. However, when I open a new terminal window, it automatically runs conda activate base, like this:
`conda activate base (bioinfo) [misakaheb@centos ~]$ conda activate base (base) [misakaheb@centos ~]$`

Could this be an issue with Visual Studio Code, and can someone please tell me what I should do? Thank you very much!